# Cloze questions without solution environment does not work in R/exams

Tags: r, moodle, sweave, r-exams

I tried one of the R/exams examples posted in the forum and tried to create Moodle questions but I get following error message.

```
exams2moodle("sample_1.Rnw")
## Error in split.default(solutionlist, gr) : first argument must be a vector.
```

The same also happens in other `exams2xyz()` interfaces.

The example is a cloze question (without solution environment) in Sweave format: `sample-1.Rnw`.

```
\begin{question}
What is the capital of Germany? ##ANSWER1##
What is the population of Germany's capital (in millions)? ##ANSWER2##

\begin{answerlist}
  \item Bonn
  \item Berlin
  \item Munich
  \item Hamburg
  \item 
\end{answerlist}
\end{question}

\exname{German capital}
\extype{cloze}
\exclozetype{schoice|num}
\exsolution{0100|3.669495}
\extol{0.1}
\exshuffle{TRUE}
```

Comment: I cannot replicate this. For me the exercise works as intended. Could you please check that `Sample_1.Rnw` really contains the Sweave content you posted above? Additionally, the mismatch in your post between `sample_1.Rnw` (with lower case s) and `Sample_1.Rnw` (with upper case s) is somewhat suspicious. Please make sure that you are using the correct exercise.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. yes, I changed the lower case s to upper case that match with the sweave file. Still the same error message pops up as below. exams2moodle("Sample_1.Rnw")
Error in split.default(solutionlist, gr) : 
  first argument must be a vector

Comment: OK, thanks for checking. I identified the problem now: Using the `exshuffle` option was not yet supported for `cloze` exercises without solution environment. I'll post a full answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem only occurs in R/exams up to version 2.3-6 (the CRAN release version at the time of writing) in cloze questions without solution environment but with enabled `exshuffle` option. The easiest solution is to install version 2.4-0 where the bug has been fixed already.

Alternatively, you could also work around the problem by adding a `{solution}` (including a suitable `{answerlist}`) or omitting the `exshuffle` option. But installing the fixed R/exams version is, of course, preferred.

Comment: Brilliant! You are great!. Updated the new version and It works . Thank you sooooooo much for your time. Much appreciated. Have a great weekend!